# Create my own start up choices from CD autostart

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation

I'm not really sure how to dig out this question.

What I want, is to create an image file that has my C# program, user manual and video tutorials in it. When the CD already started there will be a pop up form of choices which contains Install Program, View User Manual or View Video Tutorials. How can I do that?

It's similar when you're installing the Visual Studio 2008 or 2010.

Sorry for the title.
I don't know what tags should I put here.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a c# question to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a file called [autorun.inf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorun.inf) onto a CD, you can have that CD launch a program when it's inserted.  From here, you can create a program that contains the menu you'd like, so that when the user inserts the CD your menu pops up.  It's not nearly as hard as it may seem.

Comment: so basically all i need to do is create a program that do process start?

Comment: Yup!  That plus a Nice Shiny Menu, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need two files: setup.exe (your program) and autorun.inf (a text file that tells windows which program to run when you put the disk in)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorun.inf

The autorun.inf file should have this text:

```
[autorun] 
open=setup.exe 
icon=setup.exe,0
label=My install CD
```